# How do I properly verify a webhook url in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, webhooks

I am integrating an API and setting up a webhook for my app. The API provider requires that new webhook urls go through a one time verification by returning a token posted to the newly created webhook url.

I have not worked with webhooks before, and cannot seem to verify the url. Below is my controller and route:

Controller:

```
    class WebhooksController < ApplicationController

      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

      def receive
        raw_body = request.body.read
        json = JSON.parse raw_body
        # Return verification token only once for intitial webhook setup.
        token = json['data']['token']

        # The webhook normally only requires a 200/ok in return
        # but for the intial setup I want to return the received token in response.
        render :json => token
      end

    end
```

Route:

```
    post '/webhooks/receive' => 'webhooks#receive'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on what you want to return. Is it supposed to be a JSON object like this?

```
{ token: 'a token here' }
```

Then you probably want:

```
render :json => { token: token }
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, you are right. The problem seems to be that the API provider is very unclear about what needs to be returned to verify the URL.